# Python PIL to draw a circle-segment of sunshine

Tags: python, math, python-imaging-library, trigonometry

I've got a problem for which I want to draw a circle/object at a certain position in an image, and then I want to draw rays emanating from that image--with each ray being separated by 1 degree. The rays would only be cast on a 145 degree segment, though--so it doesn't form a full circle. I am using Python PIL (to which I am a novice) to accomplish that task--although I'm not strict on language requirements.

```
def drawSunshine(im):
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
    x, y = im.size
    draw.ellipse((370,200, 400,230), fill='red',outline='black')
    draw.line((370,205,390,218), fill='black',width=3)
    draw.point((100,100),'red')
    im.show()
```

I was thinking that I could start by iterating over every pixel around the circle. And then I could just change the colour of that pixel.

**Edit** *This approach made sense to me because I was planning on drawing this image on a black-and-white PNG file. If the current pixel was white, I was going to draw another pixel of the line, if the current pixel was black: I would consider it to be an obstacle and terminate the line at that point.*

However, the main questions:

- How do I iterate around an object at an arbitrary position in an image such that the area around said object is a circle or a circle segment?
- And, how do I ensure that each "ray" I'm drawing per pixel is separated by a 1 degree?
- **EDIT** Is there a way to allow for these "rays" to be interrupted by black pixels?

Comment: Draw them as triangles instead, centre of the circle, and then two points off the edge of the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a little function you can adjust;

```
import Image, ImageDraw
from math import sin, cos, pi


width, height = 400, 400

skyBlue = (135, 206, 235)

im = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), skyBlue)


#Draw Sun
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

def drawSun(draw, centre, radius, rays=False, startAngle=0, finishAngle=360, rayAngle=10, rayGap=10, rayLength=1000, rayColour="Yellow", rayOutline="Orange"):
  x1,x2 = centre[0] - radius, centre[0] + radius
  y1,y2 = centre[1] - radius, centre[1] + radius


  if rays:
    for rayStart in range(startAngle, finishAngle, rayAngle+rayGap):

      rayEnd = (rayStart+rayAngle) * pi/180
      rayStart *= pi/180

      corner1 = centre[0] + rayLength*cos(rayStart), centre[1] + rayLength*sin(rayStart)
      corner2 = centre[0] + rayLength*cos(rayEnd), centre[1] + rayLength*sin(rayEnd)

      print [centre, corner1, corner2]

      draw.polygon([centre, corner1, corner2], fill="Yellow", outline="Orange")


  draw.ellipse((x1, y1, x2, y2), fill="Yellow", outline="Orange")




drawSun(draw, (100, 100), 40, rays=True, startAngle=0, finishAngle=145, rayAngle=3, rayGap=5)

im.save("example.png")
```

[image]

Comment: That's a great answer. Thanks. But I was wondering if you could help me out with the remaining doubt I had (the one regarding the obstacles).

Comment: As in have the rays blocked by obstacles and have shadows cast?